# SASS autocompile on debian

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, compilation, sass, debian

i couldn't find any information on google for this so i thought i will just ask this general question.

we are developing a web app for customers who can change colors, fonts and stuff in their account through a simplified CustomDesigner (the name) Tab where they can pick colors from a color picker and fonts from a select-box and all this stuff.

currently all these dynamic changes are written through PHP in the CSS but we are working on a complete redesign and rework of the app and want to use the power of SASS for this.

my question is: is it possible to run ruby on a debian server and everytime a user changes some preferences in their account that ruby will compile the generated sass file or the "changed" variables into a new css file completely automatically?

if yes: how? i couldn't find anything at all about this topic.

if my using-example is not good enough and you can't imagine what i want:

think about the custom-bootstrap-builder, where you can simply change all the stuff from viewport-grid-size, fonts, font-sizes, border-radius and all that kind of stuff, and if you click on "download" it delivers a complete bootstrap version with your preselected preferences and downloads it completely automatically.

the download for my use-case is not necessary, instead i want the server to store that "compiled" file in a specific directory on the server and of course import it to the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some more research and investing more time i found some "module" for nginx which is capable of processing less/sass/scss server side with nginx/LUA

https://github.com/titpetric/nginx-lesscss

i also found a PHP variant to use

https://github.com/leafo/scssphp/

i couldn't try any of these two, but it looks quite promising and i wanted to share if someone else has the same problem.